# Add metric name in OTSDB via API

Tags: github, java, opentsdb

I am adding data into `OTSDB` from different sources. But i give metric name for each data points using `XML` file. Also i dont have any access to `OTSDB` to create Metric Name via terminal

I have reffered below links :-

[API PUT](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html)

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/issues/79)

In gitHub issue, i couldn't understand how to use `--auto-metirc` .

I know how to create metric **using Terminal** :-

Here i am creating `abxcs` metirc using terminal.

```
./tsdb mkmetric abxcs
```

But How to create metric using API?

**FYI :- Please suggest solution using JAVA**

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have metric names auto created on-the-fly, you'll need to set

`tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true`

in the OpenTSDB configuration file. Ref: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/configuration.html

> Whether or not a data point with a new metric will assign a UID to the metric. When false, a data point with a metric that is not in the database will be rejected and an exception will be thrown.

CLI equivalent of it is to pass `--auto-metric` switch while starting tsd process.